# Regular expression to split by extension but keep the extension

Tags: regex, string, powershell

Hi all I would like to split a string which has an extension `.ps1`I used the following regex

`var regex = Regex.Split(text, ".ps1");`

but I need the extension to exists in the first string. assume I have my script as follows `c:\Test\test.ps1 -Arg -Arg1`, when I split it I need the string as `c:\Test\test.ps1` and `-Arg -Arg1` as second string how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind `(?<=\.ps1)`:

```
(?<=\.ps1)\s+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c.ps1%29%5cs%2b&i=c%3a%5cTest%5ctest.ps1+-Arg+-Arg1)

**Details**:

- `(?<=\.ps1)` - require a `.ps1` to be immediately before the current location
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace symbols

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first part in group one and second part in group two

`(.+[.]ps1)(.+)`

**Explanation**

`(.+[.]ps1)` - first group with anything followed by ps1 extension

`(.+)` - second group with anything after first group